# Case Statement Mysql query to Load Data based Upon Condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying with the following sql query

```
SELECT task.id,task.Task,task.TaskCategory,task.IsComplete,
task.AssignedDate,task.CompletionDate, task.AssignedTo,task.templateID,task.ListingID,task.ClosingID,
task.ContactID,task.LeadID,task.statusid, taskcategory.taskCategoryID,taskcategory.Category FROM 
task INNER JOIN taskcategory ON task.TaskCategory = taskcategory.taskCategoryID WHERE 1=1 
and (CompletionDate = CURDATE() OR CompletionDate IS NULL AND task.IsComplete = 0) 
and assignedto = 2345 and id = 2421 and 
CASE(WHEN status_for_design = 0 THEN (leadid is not null or ContactID is not null)
THEN NULL 
END AS status_for_design)
group by 
assignedto ORDER BY task.AssignedDate ASC
```

Main Purpose is if the status_for_design = 0 [use leadid or contactid is not null, but if the status_for_design = 1

but i am facing an error

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN status_for_design = 0 THEN (leadid is not null or ContactID is not null)
T' at line 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, formatting your query so humans can read it would help you understand what is going on.

Your `WHERE` clause has an `AS` in it.  That is not appropriate.  I suspect the query you want looks more like this:

```
SELECT t.*, tc.taskCategoryID, tc.Category
FROM task t INNER JOIN
     taskcategory tc
     ON t.TaskCategory = tc.taskCategoryID
WHERE 1 = 1 AND
      (CompletionDate = CURDATE() OR CompletionDate IS NULL AND t.IsComplete = 0) AND
      assignedto = 2345 AND
      id = 2421 AND 
      (status_for_design <> 0 or leadid is not null or ContactID is not null)
GROUP BY assignedto
ORDER BY t.AssignedDate ASC ;
```

Note that the `CASE` is not necessary in the `WHERE`.  I am also highly suspicious of queries that have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can't include a `CASE` condition in `WHERE` clause like that. That's what it's complaining about. If you meant to have that in `SELECT` clause then move the case expression to the `SELECT` clause. Else, you can convert that `CASE` to below composite condition in `WHERE` clause

```
AND ((status_for_design = 0  AND leadid is not null) 
AND (status_for_design = 0  AND ContactID is not null))
```